# Exception occurred on login method of XMPPConnection in smack

Tags: java, smack, google-talk, chatbot

I wrote the following code:

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
connection.connect();
System.in.read();
connection.login("xxx@gmail.com", "***"); //Exception occurs here!
```

The exception is

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:185) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead (StreamDecoder.java:324)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:204)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:278)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2992)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1144)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:325)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)Exception in thread "main" No response from the server.:
at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:73)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:212)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:348)
```

Also sometimes I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Connection failed. No response from server.:at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:119)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:568)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:527)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:953)
```

Can anybody help me? I google it and some people said that it will be OK if you put some delay using `Thread.sleep(10000);` between connect and login. But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a proxy or firewall?
Check your connection to smack port.

In this blog has a exemple to gtalk connect, and it use SASLAuthentication class to TSL autenthication.
http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/smack-xmpp-and-gtalk/

SASLAuthentication: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/SASLAuthentication.html

Good luck.

Comment: No, I develop in Ubuntu and there is not any Proxy! Any idea?

Comment: in my answer have a link with exemple
gmail use tsl auth

Comment: OK, I will try it and response you ASAP. :-)